# What's the difference between the name argument in @Entity and @Table when using JPA?

Tags: java, database, jpa, annotations, persistence

I'm using JPA2 and both `@Entity` and `@Table` have a `name` attribute, e. g.:

```
@Entity(name="Foo")
@Table (name="Bar")
class Baz
```

What should I use, which ones are optional?

In my specific case I have a class `User` and a class `Group`, which have additional requirements (as far as I understand) because they are reserved words in SQL.

How would a working solution look like and with which name would I refer to the entity when writing queries?

Update: I added `name="GROUPS"` to both annotations in `Group` and did the same for `User`, but now I get this error:

```
Exception Description: The table [USERS] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(example.Group --> [DatabaseTable(GROUPS)])
```

and this error

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [SELECT ID, MAXIMUMROLE, MEMBERSHIPS_ID FROM USERS]
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

@Table is optional. @Entity is needed for annotating a POJO class as an entity, but the name attribute is not mandatory.

If you have a class

```
 @Entity
 class MyEntity {}
```

A table with name "**MyEntity**" will be created and the Entity name will be **MyEntity**. Your JPQL query would be:

```
 select * from MyEntity
```

In JPQL you always use the Entity name and by default it is the class name.

if you have a class

```
 @Entity(name="MyEntityName")
 @Table(name="MyEntityTableName")
 class MyEntity {}
```

then a table with name **MyEntityTableName** is created and the entity name is **MyEntityName**.

Your JPQL query would be :

```
 select * from MyEntityName
```

Comment: I (mis)learned JPA from the internet and I was providing the name of an existing MySQL table as the Entity name as a way of mapping the two.  That worked for me but only coincidentally, because Hibernate (maybe all JPA implementations?) uses the Entity name as the default table name if @Table "name" isn't provided.  However, as soon as I started using JPQL queries as opposed to CriteriaBuilder queries, I started getting "FooBar is not mapped" exceptions because I had unknowingly changed the way I needed to refer to the entity in queries.  I hope that sharing my blunder helps someone.

Answer (score 32):

The **name** in `@Entity` is for JPA-QL queries, it defaults to the class name without package (or unqualified class name, in Java lingo), if you change it you have to make sure you use this name when building queries.

The **name** in `@Table` is the table name where this entity is saved.

Answer (score 5):

`@Entity` is useful with model classes to denote that this is the entity or table

`@Table` is used to provide any specific name to your table if you want to provide any different name

Note: if you don't use `@Table` then hibernate consider that `@Entity` is your table name by default

```
@Entity    
@Table(name = "emp")     
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable { }
```