# Why ormlite don't get the correct table name by jpa Table annotation?

Tags: java, ormlite

Here is what I got.the `Table` annotation set the table name to `cbhistory_article`, but the ormlite's `TableInfo` get the table name is `article`.

[image]

How can I get the right thing ?

In `com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig#extractTableName` will find out, `com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistence#getEntityName` only get the entity name rather than table name. But why ?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262211/1870054), I think consider use the `Table` name is better or both of `Table` and `Entity` name.

Comment: Can you show the code in question?  How are you defining the entity?

Answer (score 1):

> The `@Table` annotation set the table name to `cbhistory_article`, but the ormlite's `TableInfo` get the table name is article.

You didn't provide the code that you are using to define the entity but I assume it was something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cbhistory_article")
public class Article {
   ...
```

Unfortunately, at this time [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does not support the `@Table` annotation.  I've added the code for this to trunk and it will be in version 4.49.  Sorry for the miss.  Right now it only listens to the `name` field however.  Do you need more support for other fields?

To get it to work, use the `name` field on the `@Entity` annotation:

```
@Entity(name = "cbhistory_article")
public class Article {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to work around.

```
@Inject
private void initDao(DataSource dataSource, @Named("jdbc.url") String url) throws SQLException
{
    setConnectionSource(new DataSourceConnectionSource(dataSource, url));

    DatabaseTableConfig<T> config = DatabaseTableConfig.fromClass(getConnectionSource(), dataClass);
    config.setTableName(getTableName());
    setTableConfig(config);

    initialize();
}

private String getTableName()
{
    Table table = dataClass.getAnnotation(Table.class);
    if (table == null || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(table.name()))
        return DatabaseTableConfig.extractTableName(dataClass);

    return table.name();
}
```