# How can I update MySQL table timestamp from JPA query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Here is my model:

```
@Entity(name = "checkinusers")
public class User {

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT(1)")
    private long userId;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "salt", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String salt;

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    @Column(name = "lastlogin", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date created;
```

Here is the method:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE User u SET  u.created ='0000-00-00 00:00:00' WHERE u.username = :username ")
 void updateLastLogin(@Param("username") String username);
```

This is the error I get when I try to start spring application

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run(default-cli) on project licenta: An exception occurred while running.
>   null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'userController':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract void com.example.licenta.service.UserService.update(java.lang.String)!
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [UPDATE User u SET  u.created ='0000-00-00 00:00:00' WHERE u.username = :user name ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem seems to be that JPA doesn't know the `User` entity:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped

As you specify a dedicated name in the `@Entity` annotation you need to use this name in all JPA queries on this entity:

```
@Entity(name = "checkinusers")
```

That is the query will need to be:

```
@Query("UPDATE checkinusers u SET  u.created = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' WHERE u.username = :username ")
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259273/whats-the-difference-between-the-name-argument-in-entity-and-table-when-using) for details.

Comment: Thanks for trying but it didn't solve the problem :(.

Comment: very close to right answer. Working version is :                                               
    @Query("UPDATE checkinusers u SET  u.created =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00' WHERE u.username = :username ")

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thank you

Comment: @cUser the `{ts '0000-00-00 00:00:00'}` notation didn't work? Could you perhaps comment the error that JPA reported when using my proposed query - just being curious...

Comment: It looks like the `{ts '0000-00-00 00:00:00'}` notation will only work with hibernate >= 5.0. See [the hibernate user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-literals)

Comment: That must be the problem given the fact that my version is < 5